# Define command to limited scope

Tags: macros

I would like to define a Latex command that holds only within one specific environment. So, for example in only one proof. It should be something of the form:

```
\begin{proof}
\newcommand{\test}{test}
\test
\end{proof}
```

The problem is that \newcommand and other seem to only be possible in the preamble, is there a way to do this? It would make my .tex-code a lot more structured.

Comment: Welcome! The code you wrote should work perfectly and do the job you're asking for. There is no law that disallows using `\newcommand` in the document body.

Comment: As egreg already pointed out, there is no law disallowing using `\newcommand` inside an environment. However it must then be ensured that the command is used only within that environment. I.e., the command must not go unexpanded into so-called moving arguments, i.e., into arguments of commands like  `\caption`, sectioning-commands, labels for cross-referencing. Such arguments might also be processed outside the scope of the environment where the command is not defined, e.g., in the list of figures/tables, in the table of contents or when doing `\nameref` at some place in the document, ...

Comment: Ah, wow. Ok, so what I wrote already works complete with limited scope as I wanted. Thanks for your help.